# Error obtaining the response from a Web Service call

Tags: web-services, oracle, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to consume a Web Service and, though apparently all my parameters seem to be okay, I keep getting an erro page as response instead of an array of bytes which is what I am expecting and what the WebService is supposed to return.

```
My objective is to Seal a file in order to make them only readable for the right people. I am using the IRM Oracle Web Services to acomplish that, but, though all my parameters semm alright, I can't get the reponse properly.

Acording to the Oraclel support, my request is fine, so it must be something on IIS I guess. Any help?
```

---

Exception Message:

The content type multipart/related;start="";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:ab73a894-eaf4-4293-aa4e-c3358b95ec73";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 748 bytes of the response were: '--uuid:ab73a894-eaf4-4293-aa4e-c3358b95ec73 Content-Id: Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml" Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary '.

Exception Stacktrace:

Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at HTMLToPDFComponenteConverter.sealing_services.SealingServices.Seal(SealRequest request) at HTMLToPDFComponenteConverter.sealing_services.SealingServicesClient.HTMLToPDFComponenteConverter.sealing_services.SealingServices.Seal(SealRequest request) at HTMLToPDFComponenteConverter.sealing_services.SealingServicesClient.Seal(Byte[] stream, String mimeType, SealingOptions options) at HTMLToPDFComponenteConverter.ConvertToPDF.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Exception Data:

System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Exception Source:

mscorlib

---

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal.pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Relatorio.spdf");


SealingServicesClient sealingServicesClient =
    new SealingServicesClient("SealingServices");


sealingServicesClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Irm-user"];
sealingServicesClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Irm-password"];


// Create the classification details used in the sealing options
SealingOptions sealingOptions = new SealingOptions();
// This just set several parameters which the WebService validates. (They're all okay) 
sealingOptions.classification = GetClassificationSetUp();
String mimeType = "application/pdf";
// Here is where everything goes wrong. I keep getting an error message.
byte[] sealedFile = sealingServicesClient.Seal(file, mimeType, sealingOptions);


if (sealedFile != null && sealedFile.Length > 0)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sealedFile.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(sealedFile);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

---

Meu WebConfig está desse jeito:

---

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <client>
                <endpoint address="https://url:porta/irm_sealing/sealing_services"
                        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SealingServicesBinding"
                        contract="sealing_services.SealingServices" name="SealingServices"
                        behaviorConfiguration="IrmSealingAbril">
                        <identity>
                                <dns value="localhost" />
                        </identity>
                </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
                <endpointBehaviors>
                        <behavior name="IrmSealingAbril">
                                <clientCredentials>
                                        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                                                           storeName="Root"
                                                                           x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                                                                           findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                                        </clientCertificate>
                                </clientCredentials>
                        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
        <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                        <binding name="SealingServicesBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
                     openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                                <security mode="Transport">
                                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="weblogic" />
                                </security>
                        </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Additional information: The request apparently is correct as confirmed by oracle support. However, I can't get the returning response. I thought it could be something related to the IIS, but I do not have mush skill at configuring it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem here:

[Error consuming webservice, content type "application/xop+xml" does not match expected type "text/xml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496186/error-consuming-webservice-content-type-application-xopxml-does-not-match-ex)

Thanks anyway